# Atom: disable toggle first letter lowercase

Tags: toggle, atom-editor, lowercase

I was typing on Atom when I pressed some combination on my keyword and this is what happened:

1)The first letter of every line of my document was switched to lowercase. This happened for all the documents in the folder I connected to Atom.

2) Now when I type, Atom automatically switch to lowercase every first letter of every word (separated by spaces or dots).

Does anybody know how to deactivate this toggle option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

That was a bug in a package I installed: atom-speech-to-code.

Package unistalled
Atom restarted
Now Atom works fine.